# Deleting then adding directory to branch doesn't merge correctly

Tags: git

Hey Gitters.  Here's the scenario:

I have my master with a directory we'll call woot.  Woot has a couple files in it.  I create a branch called experimental and switch to it.  I delete the woot directory and commit it.  I then add the woot directory and create files with the same names as the files that were in it previously.  I commit it.  Now, when I switch to my master and try to merge changes from my experimental branch, it deletes the woot directory (and never re-adds it).

Is this expected behavior or at least a known bug?  Am I doing something wrong?  Thanks for any help!

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Can you post scripted steps that cause it for you? (And are you using an old version of git?)

Comment: This appears to work for me too; The only thing I can think of is you've created a merge conflict by modifying master as well as the second branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you recreated the files, you did not add them. The commit does nothing. Merging this branch into the other will just do the delete. Behavior is by design.

Fix your issue by doing

```
git add -A
```

Before the second commit in your question.

Hope this helps